# Implicit declaration of function 'exp'

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Hello I'm trying to inpute answer for 3 hrs, but lon kapa said I'm wrong...

$$8x^5 e^{3y} + 11 y^4 e^{2x} = 17$$

so we use chain rule

$$40x^4 e^{3y} + 8x^5 e^{3y} 3y(dy/dx) + 44y^3 y(dy/dx)e^{2x} + 11y^4 e^{2x} * 2 = 0 $$

And I get answer

$$dx(y)/dy = \frac{-51-44 e^{2 x} y^3+33 e^{2 x} y^4}{2 (20 e^{3 y} x^4+11 e^{2 x} y^4)}$$

The function below, given by wolfram matches my answer but lon capa said it wrong...
$$\frac{-51-44 \exp(2 x) y^3+33 \exp(2 x) y^4}{2 (20 \exp(3 y) x^4+11 \exp(2 x) y^4)}$$

Comment: Second term, when you differentiate $e^{3y}$, you should get $(e^{3y})(3\frac{dy}{dx})$. You had $(e^{3y})(3y\frac{dy}{dx})$, a $3y$ where there should only be $3$.

Comment: thank Andre I'm really confused what to do next(since there are so many terms) if you have a couple min I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please make some efforts and write an intelligible question.

Comment: Finnaly got correct answer. THanks Andre

Comment: You are welcome. Apologies for not replying earlier, I was at a little computer with a screen that I basically cannot read.

Answer (score 0):

This is presumably no longer needed. Your differentiation was largely right, with a little slip, We start from 
$$8x^5 e^{3y} + 11 y^4 e^{2x} = 17$$
and differentiate, using the Product Rule and the Chain Rule. We get
$$24x^5e^{3y}\frac{dy}{dx}+40e^{3y}+22y^4e^{2x}+44y^3e^{2x}\frac{dy}{dx}=0.$$
Rewrite as 
$$\left(24x^5e^{3y}+44y^3e^{2x}\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=-\left(40e^{3y}+22y^4e^{2x}\right).$$
Solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$. We get
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{40e^{3y}+22y^4e^{2x}}{24x^5e^{3y}+44y^3e^{2x}}.$$
We could divide top and bottom by $2$. There is no other obvious simplification.